# Overwhelming of the Agenda cron jobs on the server

Tags: node.js, cron, agenda

I have about 30 cron jobs to handle pushing the notifications. I use Agenda package to handle these cron jobs. But the notification service is blocked every 2 or 3 weeks without any exception so I can't find out the reason of the problem.

Thanks in advance for any help :D